# Google Sheets Select Query using Absolute reference involving month()

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have a Google Sheet SELECT Query as below. I am expecting the query to retrieve a valid rows with the month part of the date matching the value in D8.

I am not getting any error but the query comes back with #N/A

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("sheetID","Form responses 1!A2:H"),"select Col1,Col3,Col5,Col6,Col8 where Col3='"&$B8&"' and month(Col6)='"&D8&"'")
```

Can someone please help me to reconstruct the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly Google Sheets doesn't show the "correct" error when it occurs on certain functions like `IMPORTRANGE` when they are nested on functions like `QUERY`.

`IMPORTRANGE` require authorization to access an external spreadsheet but the authorization button isn't show when `IMPORTRANGE` is nested in another function.

If you didn't this yet, put your `IMPORTRANGE` formula on an empty cell in the following way;

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheetID","Form responses 1!A2:H")
```

If you didn't authorized it yet, pass the mouse pointer over the cell to display the authorization button and clic on it.